# Changed my mind about filing with H&R block

Tags: united-states, irs

I filed my taxes with H&R block. I decided to do my own taxes online. The IRS hasn't accepted any returns yet... Can I get my taxes back?... And redo them?

Comment: You can't get your tax _return_ back and refile electronically; it is possible H&R Block filed your tax return (most likely electronically) already. But I am not sure whether the IRS has released the final version of the tax forms as yet, and so maybe your tax return is sitting on H&R Block desk waiting for the IRS to start _accepting_ tax returns.

Comment: If they've already been filed you're out of luck. Best bet is to contact H&R Block and ask.

Comment: Note that you can refile your tax return with revised numbers [if you feel there was an error in your original filing] after the IRS accepts your original filing. Look up 1040 amendments on the IRS website for info.

Comment: FYI [H&R Block and Intuit Are Lobbying to Make Filing Taxes Harder](https://psmag.com/news/hr-block-and-intuit-are-still-lobbying-to-make-filing-taxes-harder) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171005225909/https://psmag.com/news/hr-block-and-intuit-are-still-lobbying-to-make-filing-taxes-harder))